# How to import a CSV file, split it 70/30 and then use first column as my 'y' value?

Tags: pandas, numpy, csv, neural-network

I am having an issue at the moment, I think im making it far more complicated than it needs to  be. my csv file is 31 rows by 500. I need to import this, split it in a 70/30 ratio and then be able to use the first column as my 'y' value for a neural network, and the remaining 30 columns need to be my 'x' value.

ive implemented the below code to do this, but when I run it through my basic sigmoid and testing functions, it provides results in a weird format i.e. [6.54694655e-06].

I believe this is due to my splitting/importing of the data, which I think I have done wrong. I need to import the data into arrays that are readable by my functions, and be able to separate my first column specifically to a 'y' value. how do I go about this?

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'data.csv', header=None)
df.to_numpy()

#splitting data 70/30
trainingdata= df[:329]
testingdata= df[:141]

#converting data to seperate arrays for training and testing
training_features= trainingdata.loc[:, trainingdata.columns != 0].values.reshape(329,30)
training_labels =  trainingdata[0]
training_labels = training_labels.values.reshape(329,1)

testing_features = testingdata[0]
testing_labels = testingdata.loc[:, testingdata.columns != 0]
```

Answer (score 2):

Make you train/test split easy by using `sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split`.
If you don't have sklearn installed, first install it by running `pip install -U scikit-learn`.

Then

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

df = pd.read_csv(r'data.csv', header=None)

# X is your features, y is your target column
X = df.loc[:,1:] 
y = df.loc[:,0]

# Use train_test_split function with test size of 30%
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.30, random_state=42)
```

Comment: any question? ask here in the comment so I can update the answer accordingly.

Comment: I didn't test the code as I don't have the dataset. In case of any problem, ask here.

Answer (score 1):

Usually for splitting the dataframe on test and train data I use `sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split`. [Documentation here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html).
Some other methods are described [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-split-a-dataset-into-training-and-testing-sets-b146b1649830#:%7E:text=The%20simplest%20way%20to%20split,the%20performance%20of%20our%20model.) Hope this will help you!

Answer (score 0):

df = pd.read_csv(r'data.csv')
df.to_numpy()
print(df)